# Support conversion to Boolean but still have WriteLine display using ToString

Tags: c#

When I run this bit of code, `Equation(10, 20)` is output to the console:

```
public class Equation
{
    public int a;
    public int b;

    public override string ToString()
    { return "Equation(" + a + ", " + b + ")"; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new Equation() { a = 10, b = 20 });

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I'd like to support `Equation` instances being used in the test of an `if` so I allowed for implicit conversion to `Boolean`:

```
public class Equation
{
    public int a;
    public int b;

    public override string ToString()
    { return "Equation(" + a + ", " + b + ")"; }

    public static implicit operator Boolean(Equation eq)
    { return eq.a == eq.b; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (new Equation() { a = 10, b = 10 })
            Console.WriteLine("equal");

        Console.WriteLine(new Equation() { a = 10, b = 20 });

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

However, the trouble is, now when I use `WriteLine` on an `Equation`, it get's converted to a `Boolean` instead of printing using `ToString`.

How can I allow for implicit conversion to `Boolean` and still have `WriteLine` display using `ToString`?

---

**update**

This question is inspired by the `Equation` class in [SymbolicC++](http://issc.uj.ac.za/symbolic/symbolic.html). The code below illustrates that an `Equation` can be displayed via `cout` as well as used in the test of an `if`:

```
auto eq = x == y;

cout << eq << endl;

if (eq)
    cout << "equal" << endl;
else
    cout << "not equal" << endl;
```

So this is somehow possible in C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do it with a `bool` conversion but you can overload the `true` and `false` operators for `Equation`. Of course `Equation` won't be implicitly convertible to `bool` any more but you can still use it in `if`, `while`, `do`, and `for` statements and conditional expressions (i.e. `?:` operator).

```
public class Equation
{
    public int a;
    public int b;

    public override string ToString()
    { return "Equation(" + a + ", " + b + ")"; }

    public static bool operator true(Equation eq)
    {
        return eq.a == eq.b;
    }

    public static bool operator false(Equation eq)
    {
        return eq.a != eq.b;
    }       
}
```

From your example:

```
if (new Equation() { a = 10, b = 10 })
    Console.WriteLine("equal"); // prints "equal"

Console.WriteLine(new Equation() { a = 10, b = 20 }); // prints Equation(10, 20)
```

Comment: Wow, you nailed it Mike. Thanks!

Comment: While the `Equations` work in the statements you listed, it seems they don't work with the operators `||` and `&&`. Just thought I'd mention this for folks who are considering this option.

Comment: @dharmatech As I said it's no longer convertible to `Boolean`. You could overload the `&` and `|` operators, as well but it would be of limited use since you still wouldn't be able to do something like `eq && true`. I actually agree with Jon's comment that this sort of thing is a little too clever and is likely to be confusing for both consumers of your code and future maintainers.

Comment: See my comment to Jon regarding why I'm doing this.

Answer (score 12):

You can't, as far as I can tell. You could *also* provide a conversion to string... but that would then make the call ambiguous between `WriteLine(string)` and `WriteLine(`bool`).

Personally I'd *strongly* recommend that you ditch the implicit conversion to `Boolean`. Implicit conversions are almost *always* a bad idea. They make the code far more confusing, as well as leading to unintended overload changes as you've found.

(I'd also change your bracing style, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Jon, check out the answer by 'mike z'. This pretty much does what I'm looking for. Do you see any drawbacks to that approach?

Comment: @dharmatech: Well it doesn't answer the question as you put it, which is to keep the implicit conversion to `bool`. Personally I wouldn't overload the `true` and `false` operators either - I would keep things more explicit. I find that trying to be "cute" with operators like this usually leads to code which is harder to maintain. YMMV of course - but I would be very careful.

Comment: I agree with the general guiding principle that the implicit conversion to `Boolean` is to be avoided. In this case, I'm trying to emulate a feature of the libraries SymbolicC++ and GiNaC. They both override `==` such that it creates an equation object. But, if the equation is used in a test, it should evaluate to a boolean. Generally a good idea? In most cases no. But these are computer algebra systems that are embedded in C++. For learning purposes, I wanted to see how to implement this feature in C#.

Answer (score 8):

This is because Console.WriteLine(bool) overload is called instead of Console.WriteLine(object). You can explicitly cast to object and required overload will be called:

```
Console.WriteLine((object)(new Equation() { a = 10, b = 20 }));
```

Or alternatively expliciltly call .ToString():

```
Console.WriteLine((new Equation() { a = 10, b = 20 }).ToString());
```